# I want to put my paragraph on the right side of my image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in spite of my research on the internet I did not succeed in doing what I wanted to do.

I want to put my text to the left of my text or my text to the right of my image but I can't do it.

Here is the code :

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="surfooter">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item">
                <img src="img/Nike.png" alt="Nike" class="img-responsive"/>
                <p>Nike.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <img src="img/Adidas.png" alt="Adidas" class="img-responsive" />
                <p>Adidas.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.surfooter{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #466964;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .flex-item {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .flex-item p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.41em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .flex-item img{
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to change your text's, you have to change your flex-item div, which is:

In your Css script, put this:

```
.flex-item{ 
display:flex;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:flex;` on your `flex-item` div.

HTML:

```
        <div class="flex-item">
            <img src="img/Nike.png" alt="Nike" class="img-responsive"/>
            <p>Nike.com</p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
       .flex-item{
         display:flex;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your  `.flex-item` class to this hope this solves your problem.

```css
.flex-item {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this. It works.

```
<div class="surfooter">
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
          <img src="img/Nike.png" alt="Nike" class="img-responsive"/>
          <p>Nike.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
          <img src="img/Adidas.png" alt="Adidas" class="img-responsive" />
          <p>Adidas.com</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.surfooter{
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #466964;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item p{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.41em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-item img{
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  
}
```